# How do I clear the React Root Window programatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning ReactJS and I'm wondering how would I clear the react "window". I currently have two react components which I use in my main.js as such:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <LoadingScreen />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

sleep(3000).then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <SelectCategory />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
})
```

I want to somehow "clear" the window as these two containers have css that does not interact nicely.

I want to somehow do this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <LoadingScreen />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

sleep(3000).then(() => {
  ReactDOM.clearElement('root')
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <SelectCategory />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just curiosity, why do you want clear window?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(root);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! It would help OP and future readers if you could provide some explanations around the code.